# Can't print char* in WCHAR* with swprintf

Tags: c++, wchar

I have that function that work (I just have to turn wstring to WHAR* at the end):

```
wstring stringtowstring(string str)
{
    WCHAR ch[256];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, str.c_str(), -1, (LPWSTR)ch, 256);

    return wstring(ch);
}
```

But I would like to know why that doesn't:

```
WCHAR tmp[256];
swprintf(tmp, L"%s", "test");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Visual Studio in the context, this is a [documented non-standard behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=vs-2019) of `swprintf`.

> *Character and string arguments that are specified by using* ***c and s are interpreted as*** *char and char* by printf family functions, or as* ***wchar_t and wchar_t* by wprintf family*** *functions. Character and string arguments that are specified by using C and S are interpreted as wchar_t and wchar_t* by printf family functions, or as char and char* by wprintf family functions. This behavior is Microsoft-specific.*
>
> *Microsoft-specific:
> The Z type character, and* ***the behavior of the c, C, s, and S type characters when they are used with the printf and wprintf functions, are Microsoft extensions***. *The ISO C standard uses c and s consistently for narrow characters and strings, and C and S for wide characters and strings, in all formatting functions.*

Comment: I must use S, that's it ?

Comment: @Entretoize Either `"%S"` or `"%hs"` will work for VC++. Neither is [standard](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (or portable), unfortunately.